# DataTable sorting on secondary column is not working

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to sort items on the 1st and 2nd columns but it seems not working properly. Added `order: [[1, "desc"], [2, "asc"]],` to order second items in the DataTable.

```
sortingTable = $('#sortTable')
        .DataTable({
            bSort: true,
            orderClasses: false,
            autoWidth: false,
            deferRender: true,
            pageLength: 15,
            order: [[1, "desc"], [2, "asc"]],
            columnDefs: [
                {
                    "targets": [0, 2, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15],
                    "visible": false,
                    "searchable": false
                },
                {
                    "targets": [8, 14],
                    "visible": false,
                    "searchable": true
                },
                {
                    "targets": [0, 3, 4, 5, 7],
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "targets": [9, 10],
                    "type": "date"
                },
                { "targets": [2], "orderData": [2, 1, 3] },
                { "width": "50%", "targets": [4] },
                { className: "dt-head-left", "targets": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10] },
                { className: "dt-center", "targets": [6, 11] },
                {
                    "targets": [1, 2],
                    "type": "date",
                    "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                        return moment(data).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
                    }
                }
            ],
           
        });
```

HTML Code

```
<table id="sortTable" class="display" width="100%" style="display:none; min-width: 1100px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Last Date</th>
            <th>Pres Date</th>
            <th>Dr</th>
            <th>Instructions</th>
            <th>Supply</th>
            <th>Dispense Events</th>
            <th>Item Status</th>
            <th>MTable HTML</th>
            <th>PresDate</th>
            <th>LastDispsDate</th>
            <th>Long Term</th>
            <th>CID</th>
            <th>PConsent</th>
            <th>MTable</th>
            <th>RString</th>
            <th>Pres</th>
            <th>More</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Please check the screenshot below
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dPpt.png): [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dPpt.png)

Comment: When you use `order: [[1, "desc"], [2, "asc"]]` that applies initial ordering to the second and third columns defined in your table (column indexes are zero-based). There is then also a subsequent sorting operation: `{ "targets": [2], "orderData": [2, 1, 3] }`, which applies when a user clicks on the 3rd column heading (index = 2). We also have to account for which columns are actually visible or hidden (this does not affect their assigned index number).

Comment: Having said all that, which columns (by assigned column index number) are you showing in the screenshot? According to the last `columnDef` section, column indexes 1 and 2 are both date columns - and that does not match your screenshot, which has one date column and one text column.

Comment: Hi @andrewjames, updated screenshot. Please advise.

Comment: That does not help. If you are not sure how to get that information, you can [edit] your question to show the relevant HTML for the `<table>` tag and its contents. That may be more useful in helping to answer my question (_which columns (by assigned column index number) are you showing in the screenshot?_).

Comment: Hi @andrewjames, updated the question with `table` content. Please help me why I am not able to sort it properly.

Comment: @andrewjames, I am not displaying `Pres Date` on the front end as this is hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first display the table, you are sorting your data using this:

```
order: [[1, "desc"], [2, "asc"]]
```

Column index 1 is this:

```
<th>Last Date</th>
```

Column index 2 is this:

```
<th>Pres Date</th>
```

(And, just for completeness, column index 0 is `<th>Id</th>` - which is what I mentioned in my first comment.)

These column indexes are fixed. It does not matter whether a column is visible or hidden. Its index is determined based on the order of the columns declared in the HTML table - starting at zero.

So, you are sorting on Last Date (descending) followed by Pres Date (ascending).

You have not shown me your data, but I assume this is why you are getting the sort order that you see for your `<th>Dr</th>` column.

So... if that is the case, you need to change that initial sort order option to this:

```
order: [[2, "desc"], [3, "asc"]]
```

But column index 2 (which is `Pres Date`) is a hidden column. Maybe you do not want to sort using a hidden column. You can if you want to - but it can be confusing for users - and if they change the sort order they will never be able to return to the initial sort order again, without reloading the table.

Therefore, maybe what you actually want is this:

```
order: [[1, "desc"], [3, "asc"]]
```

In this last case, your data will look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. But why the sorting is not working, if I click on any of the column headers. I am not able to sort it.The sorting is mixing with each other.

Comment: This is a different problem from the original question. I do not know what you mean by "_The sorting is mixing with each other._". In one of my comments I did point out the danger of using this: `{ "targets": [2], "orderData": [2, 1, 3] }`. Do you need this? Apart from that, when I use your code (and when I fix the original problem) I have no sorting issues. You can ask a new question about this - but you would need to provide the raw data you are using, and you would need to describe the "mixing with each other" problem more clearly.